# Bind in blazor is delayed by 1 step

Tags: binding, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm sorry because my english is pretty bad.
I have a problem and would love to get some help.

I'm trying to get return value from component and update it in another component.
[image]

When component B's product selection button is pressed, the selected product will be bound to the main screen, then an item will be updated again in component A.

The weird thing is that the first time I select, nothing happens. The second time I select the product, the first item is added to component A.

Even in component A itself, when I increase or decrease the number of products, the data in component A itself gets the same error.

Here is my source code

[Component A](https://github.com/hungnt03/BlazorApp/blob/main/Blazor.Local/Shared/Components/Sellers/ProductBuyed.razor)

[Component B](https://github.com/hungnt03/BlazorApp/blob/main/Blazor.Local/Shared/Components/Sellers/ProductCard.razor)

[Main Screen](https://github.com/hungnt03/BlazorApp/blob/main/Blazor.Local/Pages/Sellers/Index.razor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In index.razor you have two `async void` methods. Make them `async Task`  and await them in C#.

`async void` runs unobserved, there is no UI update when they finish. You should never need `async void` in Blazor. Blazor supports `async Task` for eventhandlers.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake. In index.blazor, SellerService.SearchProducts will call the api to get the data. Looks like the asynchronous processing has propagated to the file razor. How I can quell the spread handled asynchronously?.

Comment: Async usually is a good thing. But it ripples through your code, all calling methods must be async and `await` for their results. Do not use `async void`, `.Result` or `.Wait()`.

Comment: I'm very grateful for what you did for me. async void is a fire-and-forget action, it won't be listened to when it finishes and no interface updates are made. To fix say I switched to async task, and everything worked properly.